# Javascript File checking

Tags: javascript

I have to check whether a file is open or not by JavaScript.

Suppose i have a file opened and the path of the file is C:\myfolder\myfile.txt
I want to check by javascript whether that file is opened or closed.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean in a webbrowser? You can't. The browser sandboxes you in.

Do you mean some other platform? If so, specify which and I'll edit or delete this answer, as appropriate.